# How to perform image search in mongodb database?

Tags: mongodb, react-native

I am making an e-commerce app in which user need to find products by image upload as in the top e-commerce apps (Amazon, Alibaba etc.). I am using React Native and MongoDB as Database, How can I achieve that without using any python open CV stuff on my own?

Maybe some cloud infrastructure help me or any third-party library in python which required no code(since I am 0 in python) and do that for me?

Answer (score 0):

you can used Javascript Open Cv  library 
https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d5/d10/tutorial_js_root.html

Comment: Thanks but it would be great if you suggest me some **pre-trained models** -ish things so that I don't have to write a bunch of codes to achieve as I am zero with ML stuff